# Does impact factor of journal you publish in matter when getting a post doc?

Tags: phd, journals, postdocs, impact-factor

I have heard from quite a number of PhD students, that one can get a good post-doc, if the summation of the impact factors of the journals published by a PhD student is nearing 10. Is this true? How does the impact factors that you earn before your post-doc have an effect on getting a good post-doc? I am talking about the field of computational biology...

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: The folklore that is perpetuating in your group may be roughly true. However, it is probably a symptom rather than the reason one is getting hired to top positions. It matters much more that that person is doing good work that is respected in the community. Please don't try to "game the system" in this way as hiring is not all about numbers.

Comment: For curiosity, what is your country?

Comment: @MikeyMike India

Comment: The answer is that it *might* matter. Different places select candidates at different times in different ways. It is plausible to imagine someone on a selection committee adding up impact factors but it is more likely that they wouldn't do precisely that. However, more generally, publishing in high impact journals can only be good for your job prospects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Note: my experience is from mathematics.  I guess most will still be applicable in other fields, but I don’t have first-hand experience.]

**It probably doesn’t matter directly.**

For any kind of job application, grant application, etc, you will be assessed on (among other things) the quality and notability of your research.

*How* exactly people assess that will depend on how close they are to your work.  Specialists in your own subfield will be able to judge your work on its own merits, regardless of where it’s published.  People in related fields will have to judge it indirectly, and may look at (among other things) the prestige of the journals you publish in — but they probably have a better idea of the journals’ reputation than just the impact factor.  The impact factor may matter most when the assessment is by people outside your subject — for instance, some government research agencies or university administrations have official criteria that include impact factors or similar metrics.

For post-docs (at least in my experience in maths), the main people judging your application will be your potential research group leaders, and their immediate colleagues.  So they will be able to judge your work directly — so impact factor probably is not too relevant there.

Long-term jobs and grant applications are much more likely to be assessed, in part, by people not in your own field, or according to fixed criteria.  So for these, impact factor and similar metrics are more likely to matter.  (How much they matter depends a lot on the specific country, institution, and field you are in.)  However, I’ve never heard of the criteria being as crude as “the sum of the impact factors of the journals you published in is close to 10”.

Answer (score 4):

The answer highly depends on very specific scientific culture. For instance, in high energy physics, I know many peers who have applied successfully to post-doc programs, and their publications record have a great dispersion. I know one guy who completed his PhD at a very respectable university without any publications(only conference proceedings, which in physics in not regarded as a proper publication), and have been hired based on a grant from CERN. Moreover, I know another peer who have completed the PhD based on multiple publications having difficulties finding a post-doc. Hence, the publication record matters indirectly, being a variable specific to the domain and culture. Either way, in a limited resource world, the connections of the supervisor might play a major role. We hope that in the future there would be no problems for PhD students to advance in their research. Good luck!

Comment: This answer seems to be focused more on number of publications than the impact factor of the journals these publications appear in, which is what is being asked.